# clang++ 4.1, no crash on NULL dereference?

Tags: c++, clang

I am curious as to why under clang++/OSX the following doesn't cause sigsegv:

```
int *p = (int*)0;
cout << *p;
```

but this does:

```
int *p = (int*)1;
cout << *p;
```

clang version is 4.1

Comment: hehehehe ... just kidding, I think ... the second snippet causes a non-aligned access :) Anyway, either snippet invokes **UB**

Comment: I bet it'll segfault if you write to the zero address.

Comment: @paddy I think so too, but I became accustomed to sigsegv when dereferencing NULL as well.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to ask for any specific behaviour of an ill-formed program. Your program isn't C++, so you can't expect C++ to define how it has to behave.

Comment: as far as I know the latest clang++ is 3.2

Comment: Yes, I know it is undefined behavior, from the view of the standards.  However it does do smth definable in the OS.  Is OSX less strict with memory control?  Why does address of 1 cause crash?

Answer (score 7):

De-referencing an invalid pointer is Undefined Behaviour. That doesn't mean that a sigsev is guaranteed. Anything could happen.

Comment: but everything happening on a computer machine has a reason. the reason "it is UB" is like saying "god made it".

Comment: Nope. Saying "It is UB" means that you can't count on any behavior.